# search directory for file and remove entity from database

Tags: php, database, file, directory

OK I have a database, games table filled with games and embed field is a directory path. I need a php script that will search my db of 3000 check if the directory or file exits in my /games/ dir. if the file or directory which the file would be in is not there then remove that entity or id or game from my database.

I apologize for not being very descriptive. I was having trouble putting what I would like in words.
any way I am using mysql database. My problem is that I imported 3000 some odd games into my arcade website using a plugin that downloads the game.zip file, extracts the zip and makes a new dir in /games/game-name and changes the embed field in my db to the new location of the game files. the problem lies in an error that the plugin didn't download the game.zip and now I have games in my db that don't have a game dir or file. but the embed says /games/game-name in the db but there is no such dir.

I do hope this clears things up. I was hoping for some guidance because I can not learn enough php to make this on my own at the moment however if I see it I will understand. writing code is much more difficult than reading code for me.

Comment: 3000 is a huge db? lol... What have you tried?

Comment: you cant abstract specific problem that you only know the detail, please provide full detail :)

Comment: You need to provide more information. If you hava a standard DB with only 3000 posts you could handle it almost in any way without hitting any performance issues.

Comment: Looks like you are needing to read a PHP tutorial instead asking in forums. After try a bit and can't tell why it doesn’t work, then it is time to make a question - showing your code and a more specific question

Comment: This is a Q&A site, I can't see a single question mark in your "question".

Answer (score 0):

You could use

- [The PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) extension to access the games table in your database.
- [PHP Directory functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php) and [PHP Filesystem functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) to list your /games/ dir.

Answer (score 0):

What DB do you use? MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? Part of the code will change depending on what database are you using